# How to make JIRA board public?

Tags: jira

I have setup a Kanban board for a project. I would like to make it publicly visible (I want to show it to users that are not logged in).

Regarding permissions, anyone can browse the project and the filter query is shared with the public. Yet, the "board" menu is not available on the home page for users who are not logged in. And direct access to the board URL shows nothing else than the login form.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Which Version of Jira are you using? Perhaps the Attlassian Documentation helps.. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-do-I-make-an-Agile-board-publicly-accessible/qaq-p/140366

Comment: 7. So it is not possible, as pointed out by your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a licensed user to use specific JIRA software features:

> For example, a  JIRA Core  user viewing a  JIRA Software  project
>   would be able to see the project and its issues, but would not be able
>   to see any  JIRA Software  specific features, like Agile boards,
>   development information, or release information. These features can
>   only be viewed by a  JIRA Software  user.

Same applies to anonymous users.

[Source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver070/licensing-and-application-access-749382677.html)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Averroes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79230/averroes) and [Peter Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354800/peter-schneider), public agile dashboard is no longer possible (as of version 7). I went to use a dashboard with several custom 'Filter results' gadgets to achieve something like an agile board.